# vue-router : use parameter in meta data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks, vue-component, vue-router

I'm wondering if I can use the parameter from `path` in vue-router's meta data field.  For instance, here I am using the parameter `entity_id` in the `path`.. but, I want to also use that parameter as a property/parameter in the `meta` property so that I can use it more easily:

```
{
    path     : ':entity_id',
    name     : 'DashboardEntity',
    component: DashboardEntity,
    meta     : {
        label: 'Example',
        iwantthistobetheid: ':entity_id'
    },
},
```

The reason is that I have a breadcrumb file that lists out the routes/children/etc. and I want to display the ID in the breadcrumb.

I can do that in the above example by using `this.$route.params.entity_id` in my breadcrumb view.. but then I have to name every parameter in my routes something generic like `id` to have it display every time.

Any idea of how this might be possible or a solution that doesn't require me to either rename all my router parameters or have a huge if/else to check each routers params to display in my breadcrumb view?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
this.$route.params[this.$route.meta.iwantthistobetheid]
```

that would be the equivalent of

```
this.$route.params.entity_id
```

or if `iwantthistobetheid` = `'object_id'`

```
this.$route.params.object_id
```